# React - history.push not working after data fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have some code coming back from my database and i want to redirect in the .then - when and if there is a res , but when i put the history.push in the .then- it doesn't render anything of inside the .then
here is some code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { CreateAccount as createAccountService } from '../services/user'
import { actions } from '../store/actions';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { ...state, user: state.userReducer.user || [] }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setUser: (loggedUser) => dispatch(actions.setUser(loggedUser))
})

const CreateAccount = withRouter(function CreateAccount(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [nameI, setName] = useState('');
  const [emailI, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [passwordI, setPassword] = useState('');

  function createAccountHandler() {
    createAccountService({ name: nameI, email: emailI, password: passwordI })
      .then(res => {
        alert(res.name) //brings the res.name but when the history.push is here it doens't show the alert
        history.push('/posts')  // <= the problem!
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('err in createAccount' + err)
      })

  }

  return (<>
    <div className="wrapper fadeInDown">
      <div id="formContent">
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="name" class="fadeIn first" name="name" placeholder="name" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
          <input type="text" id="email" class="fadeIn second" name="email" placeholder="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="createAccount" placeholder="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
          <input onClick={createAccountHandler} type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Create Account" />
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </>)

}
)
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CreateAccount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should try the following:

```html
<form onSubmit={createAccountHandler}>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="fadeIn first" name="name" placeholder="name" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="text" id="email" class="fadeIn second" name="email" placeholder="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="createAccount" placeholder="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Create Account" />
</form>
```

```js
const createAccountHandler = (e) => {
    e. preventDefault();

    createAccountService({ name: nameI, email: emailI, password: passwordI })
      .then(res => {
        alert(res.name) //brings the res.name but when the history.push is here it doens't show the alert
        history.push('/posts')  // <= the problem!
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('err in createAccount' + err)
      });
}
```